# How do I appropriately set the pointer to a new structure?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, struct

I have a question regarding initialization of a new structure in c++.  I am new to c++.

```
typedef struct 
{
   int n;
   char anArray*;
}  myStruct;

void newStruct ( myStruct **ms, int x)
{
   myStruct* local_ms = new myStruct;
   local_ms->n = x;
   local_ms->anArray= new char[sizeof(char)*n];
   ms = &local_ms;
}
```

When I call newStruct with an void pointer, my intention is for it to allocate the memory in myStruct and then store the pointer to the new structure in ms, for my use later.  Unfortunately, I think local_ms is only local in scope and is thus lost upon return from newStruct.

That being said, I'm not sure how to appropriately initialize myStruct!  Thoughts?

Comment: If you're new to C++, now would be a great time to [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) and stop writing as if it were C.

Comment: Please avoid the c-style of passing things in pointers (and avoid pointers in general)

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing here about C++ language is `new` instead of `malloc`. Its sadly that I cannot modify the tags of the question to `C` because this implies I have to modify the code of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ms = &local_ms;
```

This modifies the *local* pointer `ms` to point to the other *local* pointer to the allocated structure. However, what you want is to modify the caller's pointer. `ms` is a pointer to that, so you want to modify the thing that `ms` points to:

```
*ms = local_ms;
```

But this isn't C, so you could use simpler reference semantics:

```
void newStruct ( myStruct *& ms, int x)
//                        ^^ reference to pointer
{
    // ...
    ms = local_ms;
}

// usage
myStruct * ms;
newStruct(ms, 42);
```

But the language (C or C++) gives a cleaner way to return a value from a function: you can return a value from the function.

```
myStruct * newStruct(int x)
{
    // ...
    return local_ms;
}

// usage
myStruct * ms = newStruct(42);
```

But in C++, we can use *constructors*, rather than arbitrary functions,  to initialise new objects:

```
struct myStruct {              // no need for that typedef nonsense
    explicit myStruct(int n) : 
        n(n), 
        anArray(new char[n])   // sizeof(char) is 1 by definition
    {}

    int n;
    char *anArray;             // * goes before the variable name
};

// usage
myStruct ms(42);               // don't use `new` unless you really need it
```

Now just one thing is missing: `anArray` is never deleted, giving a memory leak. The simplest fix is to use a *dynamic array* type from the standard library: either `string` or `vector`.

```
struct myStruct {
    explicit myStruct(int n) : n(n), anArray(n) {}

    int n;
    std::string anArray;
};
```

But of course, `n` is now redundant; you should get rid of it and use `anArray.size()` instead. This means that the structure itself is pretty pointless; you just need

```
std::string ms(42);
```

Comment: Thank you.  That seemed to work.  What if anArray was more complicated than a simple character array (string).  Say, a pointer to another object?  How would you correct the memory leak then?

Answer (score 1):

> "I think local_ms is only local in scope and is thus lost upon return
>   from newStruct."

Change:

```
ms = &local_ms;
```

to:

```
*ms = local_ms;
```

would help avoid the problem, which assigns the pointer of the `newStruct` object to the `*ms`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// [A] Starting with:

typedef struct
{
   int n;
   // Not char anArray*;
   char* anArray;
}  myStruct;

void newStruct ( myStruct **ms, int x)
{
   myStruct* local_ms = new myStruct;
   local_ms->n = x;
   // Fix: use x
   local_ms->anArray = new char[sizeof(char)*x];
   ms = &local_ms;
}

//  [B] Avoid myStruct **ms, use std::size_t
//      and get rid of sizeof(char) (which is one, always)

myStruct* newStruct (std::size_t x)
{
   myStruct* ms = new myStruct;
   ms->n = x;
   ms->anArray= new char[x];
   return ms;
}

// [C] Manage memory in a class (pair new/delete).
//     Btw. typedef struct is C (not C++)

class myStruct2
{
    public:
    myStruct2(std::size_t n)
    :   n(n), anArray(new char[n])
    {}

    ~myStruct2() {
        delete [] anArray;
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return n; }
    const char* array() const { return anArray; }
    char* array() { return anArray; }


    private:
    // If you do not define these, avoid copies (C++11 has '= delete'):
    myStruct2(const myStruct2&);
    myStruct2& operator = (const myStruct2&);

    std::size_t n;
    char* anArray;
};

// Still having a new without delete in the same (logically) scope - which is bad:
myStruct2* newStruct2 (std::size_t n)
{
   return new myStruct2(n);
}

// [D] Manage memory with a shared pointer.

// Still having an new without a delete in the same (logically) scope,
// but now the memory is managed by the shared pointer - that is good!
// (If there is no std::shared_ptr: boost::shared_ptr)
std::shared_ptr<myStruct2> make_shared_struct2(std::size_t n)
{
   return std::shared_ptr<myStruct2>(new myStruct2(n));
}

// [E] Avoid the pointer to myStruct2
// If you have defined the copy constructor and assignment operator:
// myStruct2 make_struct2(std::size_t n)
// {
//    return myStruct2(n);
// }

// [F] But actually it is trivial
typedef std::vector<char> myStruct3;

myStruct3 make_struct3(std::size_t n)
{
    return myStruct3(n);
}
```